# How to do a string contain in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm trying to do a string contain operation on a vertex's property in gremlin. Some of the queries similar to this work and some don't. I am unable to understand the error. Can anybody explain what the error is telling me? I would also appreciate an alternative way of doing this.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('KType', 'iam.Role').where(has('Arn', containing('aws-service-role'))).dedup()
```

> Could not find a suitable index to answer graph query and graph scans
> are disabled: [()]:VERTEX

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points. Firstly, you don't need to wrap the `has` inside a `where`. So it can be written as just:

```java
g.V().has('KType', 'iam.Role').
      has('Arn', containing('aws-service-role')).
      dedup()
```

As to the error message, I assume you are using a graph like JanusGraph, where you can disable full scans and force each query to use an index. This means that you need to create an index for any properties you may want to filter on. However, JanusGraph cannot use its built in composite indexes for this type of lookup as it is not an "exact match" type of filter. I am not sure if `containing` can be backed by a mixed index though (see below). However, if you are using JanusGraph, you have a few other options when doing text searches across mixed indexes, such as `textContaining`.

I think you have two potential choices:

1. Create a mixed index (this requires configuring an external indexing service such as ElasticSearch, OpenSearch, or Solr)
2. Enable scans for queries like this one to run without needing an index. This can be slow as it requires a full graph scan.
   .

If you are using JanusGraph, you can [read more about mixed and composite indexes here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/), JanusGraph also has some additional text predicates that may work better with a mixed index, but note that mixed indexes do not perform as well as composite ones. The down side to using JanusGraph unique predicates is that your Gremlin will not be as easy to port to other implementations.

If your graph is fairly small, you could try enabling graph scans using a line such as `query.force-index=false` in your properties file, but in general this is discouraged as full scans can be very expensive on a large graph.

It might be better to add another property to the vertex that tracks whether an ARN is a service-role or not, rather than use the string to work it out. Consider the case where one day that naming convention changes, then your string searches will no longer work.